# How to extract a single channel matrix from a muti-channel matrix without using split

Tags: opencv

I am going to extract a single channel from a multichannel matrix. Given `Mat img` is a three-channel matrix, I want to extract the first channel. Is there any handy function to do this, something like: `out = img(:,:,1)` in MATLAB. I know `cv::split` is capable of this by split out individual channels. But I want another method, since I will not use many other channels extracted.

Comment: matlab is optimized for such matrix things. In C++ you are limited to how images are arranged in memory. If your only problem is, that you don't use the other channels, then cv::split isnt really a problem. Just ignore the unwanted output.

Comment: If you only want to use less code (simpler programming) you can write a hrlper function that uses split but returns only the wanted channel.

Answer (score 5):

There is a function for this in OpenCV, sort-of to my surprise: `cv::extractChannel()`. From [the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gacc6158574aa1f0281878c955bcf35642):

C++ signature:

```
void cv::extractChannel ( InputArray   src,
                          OutputArray  dst,
                          int          coi 
                        )
```

Python signature:

```
dst = cv.extractChannel( src, coi[, dst] )
```

Description:

> Extracts a single channel from src (coi is 0-based index)
>
> Parameters
>   * `src` input array
>   * `dst` output array
>   * `coi` index of channel to extract